# Create a Navigation IOS APP

Tags: objective-c, ios, dictionary

How can i use MapKit and Google Maps to build a simple navigation APP ? 
Is there an API to create directions and routes or i need to use some sorts of web service ?
What you suggest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps API Terms of Service (linked to from the `MKMapView` documentation) explicitly forbid the use of Google Maps for navigation purposes. You would need to provide your own maps (e.g. OpenStreetMap).

Comment: Thank you! 
My aim is simpler .. i can use standard MAPS with links 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html